# Is it possible to prohibit unnecessary CopyTensor in Compile? Just like .noalias() in Eigen library?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

Turn on

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
```

First example

```
Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}, {y, _Real, 1}}, 
  Module[{tmp}, tmp = x.y]] // CompilePrint
```

shows

```
        2 arguments
        1 Integer register
        3 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(R2)0 = A1
        T(R1)1 = A2
        I0 = 12
        Result = T(R1)2

1   T(R1)2 = Dot[ T(R2)0, T(R1)1, I0]]
2   Return
```

No copytensor, result of `Dot` directly assigned to tensor register T(R1)2

Second example,

```
Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}, {y, _Real, 1}}, 
  Module[{tmp = {1., 2.}}, tmp = x.y]] // CompilePrint
```

shows

```
        2 arguments
        1 Integer register
        5 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(R2)0 = A1
        T(R1)1 = A2
        I0 = 12
        T(R1)2 = {1., 2.}
        Result = T(R1)3

1   T(R1)3 = CopyTensor[ T(R1)2]]
2   T(R1)4 = Dot[ T(R2)0, T(R1)1, I0]]
3   T(R1)3 = CopyTensor[ T(R1)4]]
4   Return
```

There is two `CopyTensor`. It seems that mma detected that `tmp` is changed later. So it first copied to new tensor register T(R1)3, and assign `Dot` result to new tensor register T(R1)4, finally copy T(R1)4 to T(R1)3.

**But this doesn't make sense to me. These two `CopyTensor` are unnecessary! Why not just assign the `Dot` result directly to `T(R1)2` the same as the first example?? For safety reason? If so, is there any hidden option of compile could turn this safety off, if programmer is sure about what he is doing?**

PS: Also there is strange assignment `I0=12` used in `Dot`, what does it mean?

This kind of copying Tensor will affect performance sometimes, for example [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8183501/1911722)

---

**Now let's see how C++ Eigen library deals with it**

Eigen takes copying issue seriously, it provides `.noalias()` to address this problem. There is an elaborate table in the documentation titled "[Writing efficient matrix product expressions](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicWritingEfficientProductExpression.html) " which lists all common situations that noalias can improve performance, I copied several case here
[image]
[image]

Comment: I see no difference in timing.  I wonder what, if anything, is the effect of `CopyTensor` here.

Comment: @MichaelE2 What if they are in a loop, and there are many such dot and assignment?

Comment: But they aren't in a loop.  I'm only saying that your two examples give roughly the same timing with `RepeatedTiming` for various size inputs.  Sometimes the first is a little faster, sometimes the second.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't know how to understand why my example shows no efficiency problem, but copytensor do affect efficiency, eg. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8183501/1911722 . and also I am learning Eigen now, it seems that they have taken copytensor issue seriously and offer specific options like noalias() to avoid copytensor, see http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html  under item "Matrix-matrix and matrix-vector multiplication"

Comment: I don't know how the WVM works, but there are (at least) two ways to execute the `CopyTensor` in your code.  The cheap way is to make `T(R1)3` point to the tensor (and copy the memory values later, if necessary, but it's provably unnecessary in this program).  The expensive way is to blindly copy the memory to a new location.  The timings suggest it is not doing the expensive way **in this case.**  It could also be CPU dependent, for all I know, but I'm assuming you get the similar timings. Can you find a simple example of an unnecessary `CopyTensor` that impacts timing?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I can't think of an example now. But now I think maybe `T(R1)2 = Dot[ T(R2)0, T(R1)1, I0]]` is equivalent to `T(R1)4 = Dot[ T(R2)0, T(R1)1, I0]]; T(R1)3 = CopyTensor[ T(R1)4]]` Since the result of Dot must be in a temporary place.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oops, I was silly yesterday, I was wrong. the result of Dot could directly stored in the destination register.